# Google SignIn with Android (kotlin) but NO pop up window to LogIn

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-signin

I've been working recently in one of my projects in Android (kotlin), and in my LogIn page I was trying to implement the Google Sign In, for my surprise I was able to log in, but I can never see the typical pop up window that pops when you press the button to sign in (in my android app), it directly redirects me into gmail sign in in the browser, and then that's how I'm able to sign in, but never get to see the pop up.

I've tried changing some of the deprecated function, but never got anything (startActivityForResult)!

`This is my code:

```
package com.example.googlesignin

import android.content.Intent import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity import android.os.Bundle import android.widget.Button import android.widget.Toast import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers import kotlinx.coroutines.launch import kotlinx.coroutines.tasks.await import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

const val REQUEST_CODE_SIGNIN = 21 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val googleButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.googleButton)


    googleButton.setOnClickListener {

        val options = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id_googleSignIn))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,options)

        signInClient.signInIntent.also {

            this.startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE_SIGNIN)
        }
    }


}


private fun googleAuthForFirebase(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {

    val credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken,null)
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        try
        {
            auth.signInWithCredential(credentials).await()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Successfully Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception)
        {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,e.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SIGNIN)
    {
        val account = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data).result
        account?.let {
            googleAuthForFirebase(it)
        }
    }
}

}
```

PD: I have only this activity and I have the xml of main_activity containing only one button to sign in. And I've done all the correct steps linking my project to firebase, if not I wouldn't be able to log in with my gmail account, but no pop up window.

Comment: Your code works for me with no issues. Check the logcat to see if there's any error shown

Comment: Your code looks also good to me. I cannot spot the issue at a first glance. But since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).